# Se detiene mi aplicación android.widget.RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero hacer un app de notas, estoy usando un *DrawerLayout* para poder acceder a mis opciones, cuando presiona "Notas" en teoría debe mostrar una nueva actividad que muestre la lista de notas y un botón flotante para añadir notas, pero al ejecutar mi aplicación y presionar "Notas" me sale el siguiente error:

> 07-17 23:35:46.149 5560-5560/com.example.oscarsierra.bladenotes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.oscarsierra.bladenotes, PID: 5560
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.oscarsierra.bladenotes/com.example.oscarsierra.bladenotes.NotasActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.ListView
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6396)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
>   cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
>                                                                                         at
>   com.example.oscarsierra.bladenotes.NotasActivity.onCreate(NotasActivity.java:32)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6875)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2711)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6396) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

y **mi aplicación se detiene.**

Aquí está el código de mi `NotasActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.oscarsierra.bladenotes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NotasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int NUEVA_NOTA = 0;
public static final int EDITA_NOTA = 1;
private NotasAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Nota> notas;
private ListView lista_notas;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notas);

    notas = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new NotasAdapter();
    lista_notas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_notas);
    lista_notas.setAdapter(adapter);
    lista_notas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
            onEditaNota(pos);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case NUEVA_NOTA:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String titulo = data.getStringExtra("titulo");
                String texto = data.getStringExtra("texto");
                Nota nota = new Nota(titulo, texto);
                notas.add(nota);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;
        case EDITA_NOTA:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String titulo = data.getStringExtra("titulo");
                String texto = data.getStringExtra("texto");
                int pos = data.getIntExtra("pos", -1);
                Nota nota = notas.get(pos);
                nota.setTitulo(titulo);
                nota.setTexto(texto);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void onEditaNota(int pos) {
    Nota nota = notas.get(pos);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditaNotaActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("titulo", nota.getTitulo());
    intent.putExtra("texto", nota.getTexto());
    intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
    startActivityForResult(intent, EDITA_NOTA);
}

public void onNuevaNota(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditaNotaActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, NUEVA_NOTA);
}

private class NotasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Nota>{
    public NotasAdapter() {
        super(NotasActivity.this, R.layout.item_lista_notas, notas);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View result = convertView;
        if(result == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_notas, parent, false);
        }
        Nota nota = getItem(position);
        TextView titulo = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        titulo.setText(nota.getTitulo());
        TextView resumen = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.resumen);
        resumen.setText(nota.getTexto());
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Y la línea que me da error es ésta:
`lista_notas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_notas);`

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo?

Comment: El mensaje de error:  *`RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView`*  parece indicar que en el XML hay un Relative Layout que tiene el id `lista_notas`, el cual tú estás referenciando como `ListView` aquí: `lista_notas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_notas);` deberías verificar tu XML y revisar qué id tiene realmente el `ListView` .

Comment: @A.Cedano ¡Tienes razón! mi `ListView` estaba identificado con otro nombre, ahora sí me funcionó.

Comment: Me alegro lo pondré como respuesta por si puede servir en un futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error:

> `RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView  ...`

indica que en el XML hay un `Relative Layout` que tiene como id `lista_notas`,  y lo que tú intentas referenciar aquí como un `ListView`:

```
lista_notas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_notas);
```

es realmente ese `Relative Layout`.

Deberías verificar tu XML y revisar qué id tiene realmente el ListView. Para evitar confusiones conviene aplicar alguna *convención de nombres* también en los layouts y en sus elementos. Por ejemplo [esta](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/03/07/resourcenaming/).